# Printing duplication once in python

Tags: python

Ciphertext is a string that I used to print the characters duplicated and their percentage of occurrence. Here is the code:

```
def freq_attack (ciphertext):
    store = ""
    character = ""
    non_character=""
    for i in xrange(len(ciphertext)):
        x = ciphertext[i]
        if(is_alphabet(x)):
            character +=x
        else:
            non_character +=x
    for char in character:
        count =(ciphertext.count(char)*100)/len(character)
        print char, count,"%"
```

the output is

```
a 400/7 %
s 100/7 %
a 400/7 %
a 400/7 %
e 100/7 %
a 400/7 %
w 100/7 %
```

Comment: That output seems unlikely ... I would expect you to be seeing a single integer (or float) printed, not `400/7`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your sample code; the `count =(ciphertext.count(char)*100)/len(character)` line is missing a closing parenthesis, for one. Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just count the characters, so use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def freq_attack(ciphertext):
    counts = Counter(ch for ch in ciphertext if ch.isalpha())
    total = sum(counts.itervalues())

    for char, count in counts.most_common():
        print char, count * 100.0 / total
```

Demo:

```
>>> freq_attack('hello world')
l 30.0
o 20.0
e 10.0
d 10.0
h 10.0
r 10.0
w 10.0
```

Your `for` loop iterates over each character in `ciphertext` one by one, which means that in the string `hello world` it'll come across the character `l` three times, and each time you count it. At the very least, use a dictionary to track counts for each letter.

The `Counter()` object is a subclass of the Python dictionary type, with some extra behaviour to make counting easier.